# Angular Material broken on chrome version 53.~

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I've an web application with AngularJS and Angular Material.

It works fine on Firefox. On chrome, just versions lower then 53.

**Firefox** 
[image]
**Chrome 52.0.2743.116**
[image]
**Chrome 53.0.2785.116**
[image]

The error begins when page is scrolled. The fields seems to be fixed.
I searched for any class with any problem, but everything seems to be ok.
I updated material design and angular to the last stable version.

[image]

Comment: which version of angular material are you using?

Comment: angular material 1.1.1

Comment: i've read that angular material resize its inputs texts, also its selects and fixed some parts in general on its CSS, check if you have the same issue with a older version of it. i would recommend it 1.0.9

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval i downgraded to 1.0.9 but the error still occurs.